# Why does a "#" in the url stop a jquery script from executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the "DynamicPage" jQuery plugin to make my pages not reload when navigating. On the index page is a image slider plugin called "Coin-Slider". The dynamic page works fine, except when  I click to go back to the index page where the image slider is. For some reason (from what I can tell) the Coin-Slider ready function isn't activating when it goes back to the index. May be something to do with the URL, as host.com/index.php works but host.com/#index.php does not. Any reason why it's doing this? I've tried including the ready function in the DynamicPage function in the js file to execute whenever the page changes, but it didn't help. Page is included below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>Liberty Design, Scarborough</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/dynamicpage.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="coin-slider/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav-back"></div>
        <div id="wraps">
            <div id="left-wrap"></div>
            <div id="right-wrap"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="background:url(images/layout/shadow-bottom.png) no-repeat bottom center; width:900px; margin:0 auto; padding-bottom: 26px;">
            <div id="page-wrap">
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="banner">
                        <div id="social"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Liberty-Retreat/195182670529660"><img src="images/layout/facebook.png" alt="Like us on Facebook!" /></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <navbar>
                    <div id="nav">
                        <div style="background:url(images/layout/gradient-up.png) repeat-x;height:20px;position:relative;top:-20px; z-index:999;"></div>
                        <ul id="navbar">
                            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="test.php">Facilities</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Where are we?</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </navbar>
                <section id="main-content">
                    <div id="guts">           
                        <!-- Content Start -->
                        <div style="background:url(images/layout/sides.png) center center no-repeat; height:373px;">
                            <div id="gamesHolder">
                                <div id="games">
                                    <img src="images/banner_img/1335800583.png" alt="Welcome" />
                                    <span>
                                        <b>Welcome</b><br/>
                                        Welcome to Liberty
                                    </span>
                                    <img src="images/banner_img/1335800633.png" alt="shop front" />
                                    <span>
                                        <b>shop front</b><br/>
                                        this is the front of the shop
                                    </span>
                                    <img src="images/banner_img/" alt="staff #3" />
                                    <span>
                                        <b>staff #3</b>
                                        <br/>this is the description for staff #3
                                    </span>
                                    <img src="images/banner_img/" alt="staff #1" />
                                    <span>
                                        <b>staff #1</b><br/>
                                        this is staff #1
                                    </span>
                                    <img src="images/banner_img/" alt="asdas" />
                                    <span>
                                        <b>asdas</b><br/>
                                        sdasdas
                                    </span>       
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       <script>
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('#games').coinslider({ navigation: true, height:325, width: 595, hoverPause: true, delay: 5000,});
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <div id="footer">
                    <!-- Cosmetics for the footer -->
                    <div id="footer-back"></div>
                    <div id="footer-wraps">
                        <div id="footer-left-wrap"></div>
                        <div id="footer-right-wrap"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="background:url(images/layout/gradient-up.png) repeat-x;height:20px;position:relative;top:-20px;"></div>
                    <center style="position:relative; top:-8px; color:#999;">Liberty Design, Scarborough - Website by Chain.</center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser are you testing it in? Firefox often doesn't fire `.ready()` or `onload` events when going back to a page as it loads the cached content. Check if the same happens in Chrome/IE.

Comment: Happens in all browsers.

Comment: Please, consider using tools like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for big chunks of code.

Comment: Apologies, my first post here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, mydomain.com and mydomain.com/#anything are the same, they point to your default file which can be index.php, index.html or whatever. The browser doesn't refresh while it navigates to the same file but diffrent hash tags like: from file#hashA to file#hashB or from file to file#hashRandom or from file#index.php to file. Since the page doesn't refresh (gets loaaded) the document ready doesn't gets fired either (it already got fired the first time the page got loaded).

First fix to your problem:
instead of linking to mydomain.com/#index.php link to mydomain.com or mydomain.com/index.php

Second fix is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sliderInit = false;

  $('#games').coinslider({ navigation: true, height:325, width: 595, hoverPause: true, delay: 5000,});
  // Adding fix
  $('#idOfLinkThatGetsClicked').click(function () {

    if (!sliderInit) {
      $('#games').coinslider({ navigation: true, height:325, width: 595, hoverPause: true, delay: 5000,});
      sliderInit = true;
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So how can I make it fire again to run the script?

Comment: The links are like that because of the "DynamicPage" script, so I can't really change them unless I choose to stop using the script. And your fix ALMOST worked. It only works if you click the home button twice. And then if you press it more, the script fires again so I have multiple instances which messes a lot of stuff up.

Comment: add a boolean var like: var sliderInit = false; and inside the clic function you say: sliderInit = true; and put an if in front of calling the games coinslider like: if (!sliderInit) ('#games').coinslider({ ....

Comment: But the same problem as before, the function only fires if you press it twice. Now it's disabled after 1 click it wont be able to fire at all?